# Uploadify uploadSettings with scriptData does not work

Tags: java, jquery, servlets, uploadify

I am sending a file to my Java Servlet via jQuery Uploadify, there are no problems while sending the actual file. But when I try to send some scriptData with file along, to process on Servlet it just does not send anything.

Here is the JS code:

```
$("button").click(function(){
        $("#uploadify").uploadifySettings('scriptData', {'length':'0.2'});
        $('#uploadify').uploadifyUpload();
});

$('#uploadify').uploadify({
    'uploader': 'assets/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script': 'upload',
    'folder': '/uploads'
});
```

And here is the Servlet code on the server side:

```
out.println(res.getParameter("length"));
```

Only output I get is `null`, while expecting `"0.2"`. I just cannot get what's wrong and any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you handle uploaded file at the server side?

`getParameter()` doesn't work if you read the request body manually. You may use [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) filter to read uploaded files and parameters simultaneously.

Comment: Exactly, he needs to use the very same file upload API as well to grab the "plain vanilla" request parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used `FileItem.getString` instead and it works like charm now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use firebug to see what exactly is sent to a server. At the very least you'll see where error happens (in JS code or on serverside)

Comment: Well, I cannot see anything on the console being sent. But when I look at DOM > window > settings (settings of the uploadify), I can see settings I'd applied, but I cannot see scriptData setting. Any recommendations?

Comment: Well that's weird, if you see that nothing is sent in Firebug, still you see server output this means that firebug is not tracking network.